# Command line tool to track time spent and traffic volume on visited websites

Tags: open-source, command-line, web, scripting

I am interested in knowing what are the top websites I visit with respect to:

- the time spent on the website
- the traffic volume of the website

The monitoring should be at the computer level (so browser independent).
If possible working on MacOS or GNU/Linux.

I found the `netstat` command on MacOS but it isn't updating continuously. I look for something more like `htop` that is continuously updating.

Do you know any programs or scripts to achieve that?

If you know some tools that *could* achieve that but need some more work on it that wold also be fine.
For example: a tool to log all connection to websites, where I would have to write a script to create the list ordered with my criteria.